# Using an image caption in Markdown Jekyll

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I am hosting a Jekyll Blog on Github and write my posts with Markdown. When I am adding images, I do it the following way:

`![name of the image](http://link.com/image.jpg)`

This then shows the image in the text.

However, how can I tell Markdown to add a caption which is presented below or above the image?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If you don't want to use any plugins (which means you can push it to GitHub directly without generating the site first), you can create a new file named `image.html` in `_includes`:

```
<figure class="image">
  <img src="{{ include.url }}" alt="{{ include.description }}">
  <figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And then display the image from your markdown with:

```
{% include image.html url="/images/my-cat.jpg" description="My cat, Robert Downey Jr." %}
```

Comment: That is a great idea! However, `site_root` is not accepted as a valid variable. When rendered it ends up as `src="{{ site.url_root }}...`.

Comment: Ah, right, that is a variable added in [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). I edited it out, so the sample code just uses a relative URL to the image.

Comment: Jekyll now includes a `site.url` variable.

Comment: A better markup would be: `<figure class="image"><img src="{{ include.url }}" alt="{{ include.description }}"><figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption></figure>`

Comment: I need more information… it's possible to put more than one image without the need to repeat the `include image.html`? I'm trying with something like `{% for image in page.images %}` but no success. Can you help me?

Comment: this is by far the best answer, because it reduces code (thus chances of error), uses the correct standard and, above all, works for more than just captions (i wanted to add a class to the image, for resizing and centering).

Comment: Is there a way to format the caption as markdown rather than just text? I want to hyperlink using markdown syntax but it doesn't work. Tried kramdown too

Comment: @zeeshankhan you can use the Liquid filter markdownify in the include as described here: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/rendering-markdown-inside-an-html-include/4186

Answer (score 396):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd still share my method of adding image captions. You won't be able to use the `caption` or `figcaption` tags, but this would be a simple alternative without using any plugins.

In your markdown, you can wrap your caption with the emphasis tag and put it directly underneath the image without inserting a new line like so:

```
![](path_to_image)
*image_caption*
```

This would generate the following HTML:

```
<p>
    <img src="path_to_image" alt>
    <em>image_caption</em>
</p>
```

Then in your CSS you can style it using the following selector without interfering with other `em` tags on the page:

```
img + em { }
```

Note that you must not have a blank line between the image and the caption because that would instead generate:

```
<p>
    <img src="path_to_image" alt>
</p>
<p>
    <em>image_caption</em>
</p>
```

You can also use whatever tag you want other than `em`. Just make sure there is a tag, otherwise you won't be able to style it.

Comment: Hi there! I am not quite sure where and how to put the CSS part...it would be really great if anyone could help.

Comment: @ChriiSchee Either you place it in the main CSS file, or you can create your own and link it to your default layout. For example, my default layout links to main.css file `<link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">` so I just add my custom CSS definition at the bottom of this file:

`// My custom css

img + em {
 display: block; text-align: center;
} //image captions`

Comment: It's a shame that CSS doesn't allow you to go up the chain, so you could target the <p> tag here based on it having an <img> and an <em>.  Something like `img+em < p {rules}`.

Comment: I can't put my finger on why but I love this answer

Comment: Given the convenience, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This works, but not for images that you have aligned to the right or left, Ex:
`![](path_to_image){: width="400" .right} *image_caption*`
Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: This does not work properly, since <em> can be the immediate html element after an <img> inside a paragraph. I had the same idea than you but it doesn't work unfortunately:

`We notice that *zero* (![Maya digit zero](0.png)) looks very different from any other digits. *zero* is definitely a special case.`

Creates:

`<p>
We notice that <img src="0.png" alt="Maya digit zero"> looks very different from any other digits. <em>zero</em> is definitely a special case.
</p>`

So, can't use it for all cases.

Comment: For me, this created a left-flushed image with a centered caption, which looked weird.

Answer (score 267):

You can use table for this. It works fine.

```
| ![space-1.jpg](http://www.storywarren.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/space-1.jpg) | 
|:--:| 
| *Space* |
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This answer is the best one.. Using pure markdown and getting what you need. Thanks!

Comment: It reduced the width from 100% for me. How do I widen it?

Comment: In case you want to have the table centered, use <center>, followed by a new line, table, followed by a new line, </center>.

Comment: To clarify @KadamParikh's comment a bit – technically this isn't "pure" Markdown. Table syntax is an extension.

Comment: This solutions adds no semantic on the generated HTML, and thus does not link the caption to the image. The solution using <figcaption> is better on this point.

Answer (score 117):

The correct HTML to use for images with captions, is [`<figure>` with `<figcaption>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/).

There's no Markdown equivalent for this, so if you're only adding the occasional caption, I'd encourage you to just add that html into your Markdown document:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

<figure>
  <img src="{{site.url}}/assets/image.jpg" alt="my alt text"/>
  <figcaption>This is my caption text.</figcaption>
</figure>

Vestibulum eu vulputate magna...
```

[The Markdown spec encourages you to embed HTML in cases like this,](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) so it will display just fine. It's also a lot simpler than messing with plugins.

If you're trying to use other Markdown-y features (like tables, asterisks, etc) to produce captions, then you're just hacking around how Markdown was intended to be used.

Comment: It's too bad that this answer hasn't gotten any attention--I really think it's the simplest and most semantically correct.  I'm particularly distressed by all the answers suggesting formatting using tables, which just wreaks of 1990s mayhem.  ;-)

Comment: I agree. However it seems not to be supported by Bitbucket yet. A pitty.

Comment: I like the clever and simple answer provided by @Andrew but I have to go with this one given that is explicit, makes use of the appropriate HTML tags, and doesn't require too much typing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new to jekyll and didn't know markdown can be used with html.

Comment: I don't think `figcaption` should be the default for image captions. The definition of `figcaption` states: 
"While the content of the <figure> element is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should not affect the flow of the document."
Which, I think, is often not the case.

Comment: the downside I see is that, even though the markdown spec says you should use explicit html, sometimes markdown is used to generate latex and then pdf; I guess it's an unsolved problem, since the smallness of markdown is important.  with that in mind I like what the person said who just put the caption in *caption* under the image.

Answer (score 16):

A slight riff on the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366422/8207) that I found to be a little more explicit is to use the jekyll syntax for adding a class to something and then style it that way.

So in the post you would have:

```
![My image](/images/my-image.png)

{:.image-caption}
*The caption for my image*
```

And then in your CSS file you can do something like this:

```
.image-caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: lightgrey;
```

Comes out looking good!

Answer (score 11):

There are two semantically correct solutions to this question:

1. Using a plugin
2. Creating a custom include

## 1. Using a plugin

I've tried a couple of plugins doing this and [my favourite is `jekyll-figure`](https://github.com/paulrobertlloyd/jekyll-figure).

### 1.1. Install `jekyll-figure`

One way to install `jekyll-figure` is to add `gem "jekyll-figure"` to your Gemfile in your plugins group.

Then run `bundle install` from your terminal window.

### 1.2. Use `jekyll-figure`

Simply wrap your markdown in `{% figure %}` and `{% endfigure %}` tags.

You caption goes in the opening `{% figure %}` tag, and you can even style it with markdown!

Example:

```
{% figure caption:"Le logo de **Jekyll** et son clin d'oeil à Robert Louis Stevenson" %}
    ![Le logo de Jekyll](/assets/images/2018-08-07-jekyll-logo.png)
{% endfigure %}
```

### 1.3. Style it

Now that your images and captions are semantically correct, you can apply CSS as you wish to:

- `figure` (for both image and caption)
- `figure img` (for image only)
- `figcaption` (for caption only)

## 2. Creating a custom include

You'll need to **create an `image.html` file in your `_includes` folder**, and **include it using Liquid in Markdown**.

### 2.1. Create _includes/image.html

Create the `image.html` document in your _includes folder :

```
<!-- _includes/image.html -->
<figure>
    {% if include.url %}
    <a href="{{ include.url }}">
    {% endif %}
    <img
        {% if include.srcabs %}
            src="{{ include.srcabs }}"
        {% else %}
            src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/{{ include.src }}"
        {% endif %}
    alt="{{ include.alt }}">
    {% if include.url %}
    </a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if include.caption %}
        <figcaption>{{ include.caption }}</figcaption>
    {% endif %}
</figure>
```

### 2.2. In Markdown, include an image using Liquid

An image in `/assets/images` with a caption:

```
This is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com)'s logo :

{% include image.html
    src="jekyll-logo.png" <!-- image filename (placed in /assets/images) -->
    alt="Jekyll's logo" <!-- alt text -->
    caption="This is Jekyll's logo, featuring Dr. Jekyll's serum!" <!-- Caption -->
%}
```

An (external) image using an absolute URL: (change `src=""` to `srcabs=""`)

```
This is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com)'s logo :

{% include image.html
    srcabs="https://jekyllrb.com/img/logo-2x.png" <!-- absolute URL to image file -->
    alt="Jekyll's logo" <!-- alt text -->
    caption="This is Jekyll's logo, featuring Dr. Jekyll's serum!" <!-- Caption -->
%}
```

A clickable image: (add `url=""` argument)

```
This is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com)'s logo :

{% include image.html
    src="https://jekyllrb.com/img/logo-2x.png" <!-- absolute URL to image file -->
    url="https://jekyllrb.com" <!-- destination url -->
    alt="Jekyll's logo" <!-- alt text -->
    caption="This is Jekyll's logo, featuring Dr. Jekyll's serum!" <!-- Caption -->
%}
```

An image without a caption:

```
This is [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com)'s logo :

{% include image.html
    src="https://jekyllrb.com/img/logo-2x.png" <!-- absolute URL to image file -->
    alt="Jekyll's logo" <!-- alt text -->
%}
```

### 2.3. Style it

Now that your images and captions are semantically correct, you can apply CSS as you wish to:

- `figure` (for both image and caption)
- `figure img` (for image only)
- `figcaption` (for caption only)

Comment: Just for completeness, if you want to use jekyll-figure you will have to add jekyll-figure to plugins in your _config.yml

Answer (score 5):

```
<p align="center">
  <img alt="img-name" src="/path/image-name.png" width="300">
  <br>
    <em>caption</em>
</p>
```

That is the basic caption use. Not necessary to use an extra plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown doesn't natively support image captions so you may want to incorporate some html (but maybe not too much). I came up with this and it worked well for me:

```
![name of the image](https://cdn.nimbusthemes.com/2017/09/09233338/Free-Nature-Backgrounds-Sunset-by-Pixabay.jpg)
*<small>image caption</small>*
```

## Result:

[image: name of the image]
*image caption*

Here on StackOverflow this produces the same result

```
![name of the image](https://cdn.nimbusthemes.com/2017/09/09233338/Free-Nature-Backgrounds-Sunset-by-Pixabay.jpg)
*image caption*
```

[image: name of the image]
*image caption*

but it *does* work in my `README.md` (`<small>` *does* make the font smaller)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `pandoc` as your converter. [Here's a jekyll plugin](https://github.com/mfenner/jekyll-pandoc) to implement this. Pandoc will be able to add a figure caption the same as your `alt` attribute automatically.

But you have to push the compiled site because github doesn't allow plugins in Github pages for security.

Comment: Thanks. So markdown alone is not capable of creating captions?

Comment: I believe it depends on the converter you use, however, markdown standard doesn't support adding captions.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew's @andrew-wei answer works great. You can also chain a few together, depending on what you are trying to do. This, for example, gets you an image with alt, title and caption with a line break and bold and italics in different parts of the caption:

```
img + br + strong {margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px; font-style:italic; font-size: 12px; }
img + br + strong + em {margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 12px; font-style:italic;}
```

With the following `<img>` markdown:

```
![description](https://img.jpg "description")
***Image:*** *description*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest (but not prettiest) solution: make a table around the whole thing. There are obviously scaling issues, and this is why I give my example with the HTML so that you can modify the image size easily. This worked for me.

```
| <img src="" alt="" style="width: 400px;"/> |
| My Caption |
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kramdown, you can use `{:refdef: style="text-align: center;"}` to align center

```
{:refdef: style="text-align: center;"}
![example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg){: width="50%" .shadow}
{: refdef}
{:refdef: style="text-align: center;"}
*Fig.1: This is an example image. [Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg)*
{: refdef}
```

You need to add `{::options parse_block_html="true" /}` at the beginning of the post for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This option might seem complicated on the surface, but it is not at all and  solves other problems that the Jekyll markdown renderer (Kramdown) has. Basically this option changes the renderer for one made with python that is expandable, allowing you to instally extensions (there are a ton, markdown-captions for example) and expand it (it has an extension API).

1. The first step is to define a custom markdown processor. You will have to add `markdown: CustomProcessor` to the `_config.yml`.
2. Then, we have to create the CustomProcessor. Create a folder called `_plugins` and add a file called `MyConverter.rb` with this content:

```rb
class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::CustomProcessor

    def initialize(config)

    end

    def matches(ext)
        ext =~ /^\.(md|markdown)$/i
    end

    def output_ext(ext)
        ".html"
    end

    def convert(content)

      puts "EXECUTED"

      md_path = "./_plugins/temp/temp.md"
      html_path = "./_plugins/temp/temp.html"
      
      File.write(md_path, content, mode: "w")
      system("python ./_plugins/MyConverter.py")

      content = File.read(html_path)
      content
    end
end
```

You will also need to create a folder `temp` inside `plugins`.

All that code does is to write all the content of the file we are processing to temp.md, call a python script, wait until it finishes, read temp.html, and return it as the output of the converter.

3. Now it is time to create our converter in python. I have choosen to use [Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/). It is easy to use and has a ton of extensions. To use the converter we have to create a file called `MyConverter.py` inside the `_plugins` folder and put this content inside:

```py
import markdown

markdown_extensions = [
    'markdown_captions',
    'def_list',
    'nl2br',
    'tables',
    'codehilite',
    'fenced_code',
    'md_in_html',
    'attr_list'
]

md_file = open("./_plugins/temp/temp.md", "r")
md_string = md_file.read()
md_file.close()

html_string = markdown.markdown(md_string, extensions=markdown_extensions, extension_configs =extension_configs)

html_file = open("./_plugins/temp/temp.html", "w")
html_file.write(html_string)
html_file.close()
```

That code just loads the extensions, reads `temp.md` file, converts it to html and writtes it to `temp.html`. Using all those extensions should generate a similar output to the default jekyll markdown rendere. The only extension that is not bundled with python-markdown is markdown_captions, the one that does the magic. To install the python renderer and the extension you just have to run `pip install Markdown markdown-captions`.

That should do it, now your markdown is being translated by Python-Markdown. Some html elements my be different now (in my experience just a few) so maybe you have to make small changes in the css.

This is the css that I am using with the camptions:

```css
figure{
  margin: 0px;
}

figcaption { 
  color: gray;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

The process tries to be as simple as possible to make it easy to understand and modify. I have described the process as well as I could remember. If anybody has a problem just leave a comment and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following config in the `_config.yml` file

```
# prose.io config
prose:
  rooturl: '_posts'
  media: 'img'
  ignore:
    - 404.html
    - LICENSE
    - feed.xml
    - _config.yml
    - /_layouts
    - /_includes
    - /css
    - /img
    - /js
  metadata:
    _posts:
      - name: "layout"
        field:
          element: "hidden"
          value: "post"
      - name: "title"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Post title"
          placeholder: "Title"
          alterable: true
      - name: "subtitle"
        field:
          element: "textarea"
          label: "Subtitle"
          placeholder: "A description of your post."
          alterable: true
      - name: "date"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Date"
          help: "Enter date of post."
          placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd"
          alterable: true
      - name: "image"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Image"
          help: "Add a thumbnail image to your post."
          placeholder: "Thumbnail"
          alterable: true
      - name: "published"
        field:
          element: "checkbox"
          label: "Publish"
          help: "Check to publish post, uncheck to hide."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript that automatically generates a figcaption from the image's alt.

You can add some css to make the bottom text look more realistic.

The same applies to markdown. Whatever text you put `![HERE]()` appears below the image.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var altText = images[i].getAttribute("alt");
    var figcaption = document.createElement("figcaption");
    figcaption.innerHTML = altText;
    images[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", figcaption);
}
```

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var altText = images[i].getAttribute("alt");
    var figcaption = document.createElement("figcaption");
    figcaption.innerHTML = altText;
    images[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", figcaption);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@IQAndreas's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19360305/14516016), I wrote a small "tags plugin" that introduces the "image" tag into your markdown, which does exactly what @IQAndreas's answer does except no need to include or anything.

Here's `_plugins/image.rb`

```rb
# Licensed under CC0 Public Domain License,
# Read More: https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

module Jekyll
  class ImageTag < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @opts = parse_options(text)
    end

    def render(context)
      return "<figure class=\"image\"><img src=\"#{@opts[:src]}\" alt=\"#{@opts[:alt]}\"><figcaption>#{@opts[:alt]}</figcaption></figure>"
    end

    # Source: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/dbbfc5d48c81cf424f29c7b0eebf10886bc99904/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb#L56
    OPTIONS_REGEX = %r!(?:\w="[^"]*"|\w)+!.freeze
    def parse_options(input)
      options = {}
      return options if input.empty?

      # Split 1 possible form -- key="value"
      input.scan(OPTIONS_REGEX) do |opt|
        key, value = opt.split("=")
        # Remove Quotes
        if value&.include?('"')
          value.delete!('"')
        end
        if value
          options[key.to_sym] = value
        end
      end

      return options
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('image', Jekyll::ImageTag)
```

And then you can use it like so in your Markdown files:

```
{% image src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/320x240" alt="Random 320x240 Image" %}
```

**Note**: One of the reasons You may **NOT** want to use this is that the "option parsing" being done here is super basic, and can easily break when you introduce `"` inside the key-value pair.

I will be more than glad if someone can help improve that.