# Including a picture in a markdown file in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, markdown

i have to write a document using markdown in vscode.
I have some troubles including images in my file. I want to have a caption for my image.
I tried the suggestion on thist [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331362/using-an-image-caption-in-markdown-jekyll). Therefore i created a folder "_includes" and i added a file image.html with the following code:

```
<figure class="image">
<img src="{{include.url}}" alt="{{include.description}}">
<figcaption>{{include.description}}</figcaption>
```

In my .md-file im trying to include the image using

```
{% include image.html src="/pictures/myimage.svg" description="test" %}
```

The problem is, vscode doesn't seem to recognize the {% include %} command. It just shows the code as plain text.
Can anyone recommend me to a solution for this problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366422/14488588) answer worked best for me. Here's the code:

```
![](path_to_image)
*image_caption*
```

I also liked the output of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191209/14488588) one better visually,  but they're both fine functionally. Code:

```
| ![space-1.jpg](http://www.storywarren.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/space-1.jpg) | 
|:--:| 
| *Space* |
```

(I would add this as a comment, but I'm too new here to comment, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the pics to my project library, then dragged and dropped in markdown. Take care to press shift and also drop the pic in the rectangle prepared for inserting text, not just anywhere.